# debug server side rendered component with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would  like  to know  how  to display  any log inside  a server rendered component  using  reactjs? 
i already tried  using console.log, console.error with not luck

Comment: What are you server side rendering with?

Comment: Which server u use ? http of nodejs ? nginx ?....?

Answer (score -1):

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1337`

`new Image('http://localhost:1337/hello-world')`